# Can I use a GeometryReader to make a dynamic text size?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an app that has a view made of 8 `VStack`s of `Text` elements with an `Image` at the center.  This works great on larger phones and tablets but on smaller phones, the `Image` gets resized so small so that the text content around it can fit.
I am using hardcoded font sizes.  Is it a solution to this using a dynamic font size with the use of `GeometryReader` so that I can have a small "base" font size that will look decent on small screens and for large screens, I can have a multiplier based on the screen height?

Comment: When you say “dynamic text size”, do you mean Apple's [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically?language=objc) system for allowing the user to scale the text according to their needs? Or do you mean something else? Editing your question to include some code would also be a good idea. It's not clear why you would have “8 VStacks of Text elements” as opposed to one `VStack` containing 8 `Text`s.

Answer (score 1):

See option three for `GeometryReader`.

Yes, and here are three ways to do so (but only one uses `GeometryReader`).

**Option One** - `@ScaledMetric`

SwiftUI has a property wrapper called `ScaledMetric` - here are the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scaledmetric.

This is a dynamic property that scales a numeric value.

So this means that you could assign your font sizes to variables, make them `ScaledMetric`s, and then they would auto-adjust. Here is some sample code for how to implement this first option:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    @ScaledMetric(relativeTo: .body) var fontSize = 50

    var body: some View {
        Text("This will be scaled according to the Body font.")
        .font(.system(size: fontSize))
    }
}
```

**Note**: while you don't have to use the `relativeTo` property, this will ensure it scales according to that font. That property is a [`Font.TextStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/textstyle).

- Citation: I used this article by *Hacking With Swift* for information: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-scaledmetric-property-wrapper.

**Option Two** - `relativeTo` in `Font.Custom`

SwiftUI provides the `.font` View Modifier. When initializing a font with this modifier, fill in the `relativeTo` field. See the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/custom(_:size:relativeto:).

Example:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This will be scaled according to the Body font.")
        .font(.custom("Times New Roman", size: 24, relativeTo: .body))
    }
}
```

And once again, that `relativeTo` property is a is a [`Font.TextStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font/textstyle). This will scale the `Text` according to how that default font would normally scale.

**Option three** - `GeometryReader`

Using a `GeometryReader`, you can get the width and height of a screen. Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader. Here is an article that I used for some information, and has a lot of good stuff: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader.

Here is an example:

```swift
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            Text("This will be scaled by screen height.")
            .font(.custom("Times New Roman", size: geo.size.height * 0.05))
        }
    }
}
```